Minting a token with Transferhook
I'm not sure if something has updated recently, but code I am using has stopped working.
// Prepare metadata
      const metaData: TokenMetadata = {
        updateAuthority: mintAuthority,
        mint: mint,
        name: tokenMetadata.tokenName,
        symbol: tokenMetadata.symbol,
        uri: uri,
        additionalMetadata: [["description", tokenMetadata.description]],
      };

      const mintExtensions = [ExtensionType.MetadataPointer];
      if (isSupplyLimiterOn) mintExtensions.push(ExtensionType.TransferHook);
      if (isTaxOn) mintExtensions.push(ExtensionType.TransferFeeConfig);

      const metadataExtension = TYPE_SIZE + LENGTH_SIZE;
      const metadataLen = pack(metaData).length;
      const mintLen = getMintLen(mintExtensions);
      const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
        mintLen + metadataExtension + metadataLen
      );

      // Create instructions
      const instructions = [
        ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ microLamports: 3.33 * 1e6 }),
        ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
          units: isSupplyLimiterOn ? 250_000 : 200_000,
        }),
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
          fromPubkey: mintAuthority,
          newAccountPubkey: mint,
          space: mintLen,
          lamports,
          programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
      ];

      if (isTaxOn) {
        const withdrawWithheldAuthority = new PublicKey(
          taxWallet || mintAuthority
        );
        const feeBasisPoints = Number(taxPercent) * 100;
        const maxFee = BigInt(tokenMetadata.supply * 10 ** decimals);
        instructions.push(
          createInitializeTransferFeeConfigInstruction(
            mint,
            mintAuthority,
            withdrawWithheldAuthority,
            feeBasisPoints,
            maxFee,
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
          )
        );
      }

      instructions.push(
        createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
          mint,
          mintAuthority,
          mint,
          TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        ),
        createInitializeMintInstruction(
          mint,
          decimals,
          mintAuthority,
          mintAuthority,
          TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        ),
        createInitializeInstruction({
          programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
          metadata: mint,
          updateAuthority: mintAuthority,
          mint: mint,
          mintAuthority: mintAuthority,
          name: metaData.name,
          symbol: metaData.symbol,
          uri: metaData.uri,
        }),
        createUpdateFieldInstruction({
          programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
          metadata: mint,
          updateAuthority: mintAuthority,
          field: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][0],
          value: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][1],
        })
      );
      if (isSupplyLimiterOn) {
        const [extraAccountMetaListPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
          [
            Buffer.from("extra-account-metas"),
            mintKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer(),
          ],
          supplyProgramId
        );
        const [configPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
          [Buffer.from("config"), mintKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer()],
          supplyProgramId
        );
        instructions.push(
          createInitializeTransferHookInstruction(
            mintKeypair.publicKey,
            wallet.publicKey,
            supplyProgramId,
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
          )
        );
        const maxWallet = Math.min(
          Math.max(Number(maxWalletPercent) || 100, 0),
          100
        );
        const maxTax = Math.min(
          Math.max(Number(maxTransactionPercent) || 100, 0),
          100
        );
        const supplyHookIx = await createSupplyHook(
          wallet.publicKey,
          mint,
          extraAccountMetaListPDA,
          configPDA,
          maxWallet * 10000,
          maxTax * 10000
        );
        instructions.push(supplyHookIx);
      }
      const userATAKey = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mint,
        mintAuthority,
        true,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      );
      instructions.push(
        createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotentInstruction(
          mintAuthority,
          userATAKey,
          mintAuthority,
          mint,
          TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        ),
        createMintToInstruction(
          mint,
          userATAKey,
          mintAuthority,
          BigInt(tokenMetadata.supply * 10 ** tokenMetadata.decimals),
          undefined,
          TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        )
      );

      const globalAddressLookupTableAddress = new PublicKey(
        "HXymiEoZzgb5emVa1NLexeMqmwx1wQegTB3dN6Yh8x1i"
      );
      const lookupTableAccount = (
        await connection.getAddressLookupTable(globalAddressLookupTableAddress)
      ).value;
      const blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

      const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: wallet.publicKey,
        recentBlockhash: blockhash.blockhash,
        instructions,
      }).compileToV0Message([lookupTableAccount!]);

      const transaction = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
      transaction.sign([mintKeypair]);
      const signedTransaction = await wallet.signTransaction!(transaction);
      const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
        signedTransaction.serialize(),
        { skipPreflight: true }
      );

      await connection.confirmTransaction({
        signature,
        blockhash: blockhash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: blockhash.lastValidBlockHeight,
      });

This exact code worked for a long time but noticed recently I receive this error when attempting to deploy if I enable "supply limiter" to utilize my transferhook.
#5 - Token 2022 Program: initializeMint
(Program Error: "invalid account data for instruction")

You need to initialize the transfer hook configuration before initializing the mint. Meaning:
          createInitializeTransferHookInstruction(
            mintKeypair.publicKey,
            wallet.publicKey,
            supplyProgramId,
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
          )

Needs to come before:
        createInitializeMintInstruction(
          mint,
          decimals,
          mintAuthority,
          mintAuthority,
          TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        ),


i have a code that is working, very similar to what you are doing (checked initializeMint & transferHookInstruction), the only thing that was different on my side is that the transfer hook ix is before the initialize mint ix in my tx. I don't know if it is related... might be worth a shot.
